# EF 5 Code First Adding New Table With Seeding

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have my database setup as I want it and am just making tweaks to existing tables and adding the occasional new table, and live data has been added to the table after the initial seeding.  So if I want to add a new table and seed just this table while leaving the data in the other tables as it is, is this possible?  I do not want to drop the existing tables or lose the existing data, I just want to add a new table and seed it with data at the same time as creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know if there's a better way of doing this.

When I add a model, then in my Migrations/Congiruation.cs file I add the appropriate seeding values and basically just comment out the rest.  ie:

```
var Locations = new List<Location>
{
    new Location { Suburb="Sydney", Postcode = "2000", State = "NSW"}
};

Locations.ForEach(s => context.Locations.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

for a new Location model.  Unless you have set drop database if model changes in your initialiser, then running update-database in your package manager console will not affect any of your other tables or data.